# Difference in conductivities of metals and semiconductors based on quantum theory

Tags: semiconductors, conductivity, metal

According to Fermi-Dirac statistics, in a metal, only certain number of valence electrons take part in conduction when they acquire an energy equivalent to KT for some temperature. Now my questions is: How is this different from conduction in a semiconductor where the concentration of conduction electrons also depends on the temperature due to breakage of covalent bonds? Why should resistivity due to electronic vibrations play a larger role in a metal than in a semiconductor? Note: I have just finished an undergrad course on quantum mechanics where we dealt with conduction in metals.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  There is no band gap in metals so they stay as good conductors down to absolute zero.  In a semiconductor there is a band gap, and even when doped the doping impurities lie in the gap, such that the carriers "freeze out" at some temperature.  [Here's](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/extrinsi.htm) something on doped semiconductors.